# Mongoid authorize config does not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passwords, mongoid, authorize

Using mongoid on rails

```
gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.4'
gem 'mongoid', '~> 6.1.0'

Mongodb version: 3.4.10
```

My mongoid.yml

```
development:
  clients:
    default:
      database: xxxx_development
      hosts:
        - xxx.xx.147.208:2200
      user: 'root'
      password: "xxxxxxxx"
      auth_source: admin
```

The user root is with the root role. The user/password can work with MongoBooster and mongo cli, I mean can db.xxx.find({}).

But in my rails app, it just throws

```
MONGODB | Topology type 'unknown' initializing.
MONGODB | Server xxx.xx.147.208:2200 initializing.
MONGODB | Topology type 'unknown' changed to type 'single'.
MONGODB | Server description for xxx.xx.147.208:2200 changed from 'unknown' to 'standalone'.
MONGODB | There was a change in the members of the 'single' topology.
MONGODB | xxx.xx.147.208:2200 | xxxx_development.count | STARTED | {"count"=>"news", "query"=>{}}
MONGODB | 116.62.147.208:2200 | xxxx_development.count | FAILED | not authorized on xxxx_development to execute command { count: "news", query: {} } (13) | 0.153356s
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 364ms
```

I have tried many different configs, but can't make mongoid authorize work.
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
MONGODB | Topology type 'unknown' initializing.
MONGODB | Server xxx.xx.147.208:2200 initializing.
MONGODB | Topology type 'unknown' changed to type 'single'.
MONGODB | Server description for xxx.xx.147.208:2200 changed from 'unknown' to 'standalone'.
MONGODB | There was a change in the members of the 'single' topology.
```

These are errors I got, as well, on my development environment, but not on any other environments.

My config:

- Rails 4.2.10
- Mongoid 5.2.1
- Mongodb 3.4.4
- MacOS Sierra 10.12.6

And this error was not caused by mongoid authorize work, in my case, but by random query..
I'm still looking for what really caused this error.
Also, here is my crash report

```
12:19:03 vie2.1   |  -- Control frame information -----------------------------------------------
12:19:03 vie2.1   |  c:0005 p:---- s:0014 e:000013 CFUNC  :sleep
12:19:03 vie2.1   |  c:0004 p:0010 s:0010 e:000009 BLOCK  /Users/7in4/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/mongo-2.4.3/lib/mongo/cluster/cursor_reaper.rb:168 [FINISH]
12:19:03 vie2.1   |  c:0003 p:---- s:0008 e:000007 CFUNC  :loop
12:19:03 vie2.1   |  c:0002 p:0009 s:0005 e:000004 BLOCK  /Users/7in4/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/mongo-2.4.3/lib/mongo/cluster/cursor_reaper.rb:167 [FINISH]
12:19:03 vie2.1   |  c:0001 p:---- s:0002 e:000001 (none) [FINISH]
12:19:03 vie2.1   |  -- Ruby level backtrace information ----------------------------------------
12:19:03 vie2.1   |  /Users/7in4/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/mongo-2.4.3/lib/mongo/cluster/cursor_reaper.rb:167:in `block in start!'
12:19:03 vie2.1   |  /Users/7in4/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/mongo-2.4.3/lib/mongo/cluster/cursor_reaper.rb:167:in `loop'
12:19:03 vie2.1   |  /Users/7in4/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/mongo-2.4.3/lib/mongo/cluster/cursor_reaper.rb:168:in `block (2 levels) in start!'
12:19:03 vie2.1   |  /Users/7in4/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/mongo-2.4.3/lib/mongo/cluster/cursor_reaper.rb:168:in `sleep'
```